# Padding to a fixed length

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to do padding (with *) to my select statement list so that all values will have same length upon retrieving.

Assuming my query is 'select distinct city from all_cities' and the list of values are boston, seattle, san francisco, san jose.

I want the output as

1. boston*********
2. seattle********
3. san francisco**
4. san jose*******

Can anyone provide inputs on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rpad`.

```
select rpad(city,15,'*') from all_cities;
```

Comment: I have tried that before. With above statement it pads * for the length of 15 for every value. But I am trying to maintain fixed length once padding has been applied. In above case, san francisco value has been padded just 2 times so as to maintain that length.

Answer (score 0):

```
select @MaxLength = max(len(city)) from all_cities; 
select rpad(city, @MaxLength, '*') from all_cities;
```

As I'm clearly not a SQL whiz, I'm sure there's a way to combine this into a single select (not to mention my knowledge of built-in SQL functions is minimal)